# React Mocha - `Missing class properties transform`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, npm, mocha.js

I'm starting to use es6 with my mocha tests, but its failing with:
`Missing class properties transform.`

**Test**

```
"test": "BABEL_ENV=test nyc mocha --watch tap 'test/**/*.spec.js'",
```

**Component**

```
class SignIn extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: 'as',
            pw: 'as'
        };

        this.logIn = this.logIn.bind(this);
        this.changed = this.changed.bind(this);
    }

    changed = ( e ) => {
        let newDeets = {};
        newDeets[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState(newDeets);
    };
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react","react-hmre"],
  "ignore": [
    "public/**/*.js"
  ],
}
```

**package.json**

```
"autoprefixer": "^6.4.0",
"babel-core": "^6.11.4",
"babel-eslint": "^4.1.6",
"babel-jscs": "^2.0.5",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
"babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
```

**Error**

```
> BABEL_ENV=test nyc mocha --watch tap 'test/**/*.spec.js'

/var/www/kindred.com/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:590
      throw err;
      ^

SyntaxError: /var/www/kindred.com/src/components/Signin/index.js: Missing class properties transform.
  17 |   }
  18 | 
> 19 |   changed = ( e ) => {
     |   ^
  20 |     let newDeets = {};
  21 |     newDeets[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
  22 |     this.setState(newDeets);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't tell mocha to use babel. You can `npm install --save-dev babel-register` and use mocha `--require babel-register`

So your test command would look like:

```
"test": "BABEL_ENV=test nyc --require babel-register mocha --watch tap 'test/**/*.spec.js'",
```

Comment: Thanks mate :) Sadly, the same errors with these 2 things added.

Answer (score 0):

babel-core already comes with the register you need to run mocha with es6. There's no need to install it.

You should try using the --compilers option. I use the following command to test my es6 applications:

```
"./node_modules/.bin/mocha --timeout 0 --compilers js:babel-core/register --reporter spec"
```

Although, the error you are getting:

> SyntaxError: /var/www/kindred.com/src/components/Signin/index.js: Missing class properties transform.

Is probably due syntax error. Try changing

```
changed = ( e ) => {
    let newDeets = {};
    newDeets[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(newDeets);
};
```

to

```
changed(e) {
    let newDeets = {};
    newDeets[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(newDeets);
}
```

For what I know, es6 class syntax doesnt allow the creation of variables in the class scope, only declaration of functions.

One more thing, in order to es6 work with the `import` (instead of `require`) keyword, I also needed to add "stage-0", to my presets in babelrc.